# Using RGB and HSL color objects in Particles.js

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am working with this library : https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/particles.js

In first few lines (starting from line 15) the developer sets some default values like :

```
this.pJS = {
canvas: {
  el: canvas_el,
  w: canvas_el.offsetWidth,
  h: canvas_el.offsetHeight
},
particles: {
  number: {
    value: 400,
    density: {
      enable: true,
      value_area: 800
    }
  },
  color: {
    value: '#fff'
  },
```

Later, around the line 269, the developer checks for appropriate value of colors :

```
this.color = {};
if(typeof(color.value) == 'object'){

  if(color.value instanceof Array){
    var color_selected = color.value[Math.floor(Math.random() * pJS.particles.color.value.length)];
    this.color.rgb = hexToRgb(color_selected);
  }else{
    if(color.value.r != undefined && color.value.g != undefined && color.value.b != undefined){
      this.color.rgb = {
        r: color.value.r,
        g: color.value.g,
        b: color.value.b
      }
    }
```

Users of the library can set all these options in a JSON file like this (https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js):

```
{
"particles": {
"number": {
  "value": 80,
  "density": {
    "enable": true,
    "value_area": 800
  }
},
"color": {
  "value": "#ffffff"
},
```

The color can be set in a variety of ways as shown in the image below:

[image]

If I set the color like this :

```
"color": {
  "value": "#f00" // It works
}

"color": {
  "value": ["#00f","#A69","#CA1"] // It works
}

"color": {
  "value": "random" // It works
}

"color": {
  "value": {r:182, g:25, b:36} // Does not work
}

"color": {
  "value": {h:356, s:76, l:41} // Does not work
}
```

How can I properly set the color in RGB and HSL format?

**Update** : `alert(typeof(color.value));` returns `string` in last two cases.

**Update 2** : I have created a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/85djnk85/5/ for reference.

Before downvoting , let me know if you need any additional information :)

Comment: so you want to be able to check for different formats of color? and then what?

Comment: I don't want to check for different formats. I want to store the data in RGB format. The library does the rest.

Comment: For that you need to know from which format you are converting to RGB format. Did I missed something? So can I conclude that you want to convert the color value (in any form) to RGB form?

Comment: No, Let me rephrase. If I use first three forms in my JSON file, they work. The last two forms don't set any color. The library is not mine.

Comment: Any errors you get? What do you mean by `they don't work`?

Comment: what about "color": { "value": {"r":182, "g":25, "b":36} }

Comment: @scottjustin5000 It did not work. The color still does not change. Let me create a codepen or fiddle.

Comment: @scottjustin5000 here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/85djnk85/5/

Comment: k, i'm not familiar with this lib, but...when log around this line 259 things look weird. the color object is logged out w/ the rgb, but value is the default ('#fff').  if i remove the default, things seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/scottjustin5000/85djnk85/9/

Comment: @scottjustin5000 Thanks :). Is this the only way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but there is a bug in the Particles.js code that applies your settings over top of the defaults.

If you use a non-minified version of Particles.js, you can add use your debugger to watch the values just before it applies your settings ([lines 139-141](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/dev/particles.js#L145-L148)):

```
/* params settings */
if(params){
  Object.deepExtend(pJS, params);
}
```

`Object.deepExtend` copies values from one object to another, recursively.
It is defined [further down in the same file](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/2.0.0/particles.js#L1416-L1427):

```
Object.deepExtend = function(destination, source) {
  for (var property in source) {
    if (source[property] && source[property].constructor &&
     source[property].constructor === Object) {
      destination[property] = destination[property] || {};
      arguments.callee(destination[property], source[property]);
    } else {
      destination[property] = source[property];
    }
  }
  return destination;
};
```

This works fine when the source and destination have the same shape, like these two:

```
var destination =
{
  old: "no change",
  shared: "default"
},
source =
{
   shared: "override",
   new: "added"
}
Object.deepExtend(destination, source);

/* `destination` will now look like this: 
{
   old: "no change",
   shared: "override",
   new: "added"
}
*/
```

A string in the source, a string in the destination. Just like your `{color: {value: "#f00"}}` example overwrites the default `{color: {value: "#fff"}}`.

But when the source has an Object where the destination has a string (like your example where the source says `{color: {value: {r:182, g:25, b:36}` and the destination (default) has `{color: {value: "#fff"}}`, its logic breaks down.

In particular, control eventually reaches [Line 1423](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/2.0.0/particles.js#L1423):

```
destination[property] = source[property];
```

And by that time, `destination` is set to a plain string, so it does something quite weird:

```
"#fff"["r"] = 182;
```

That's right, it sets the `r` property on the string "#fff". That's clearly not the behaviour you want :-)

Importantly, it means that the library's documentation and the library's code disagree with each other... pretty much the definition of a bug. I'd recommend [filing an issue](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues) and maybe trying to figure out another way to get your colours in there (one way is to use your own copy of Particles.js and remove the default color).

Comment: Thanks. After the comment by scottjustin, I had a general idea about the reason my code was not working . Now , I know exactly what's going on. :)

Comment: I have one confusion though. Why does the array version above works if the values are begin checked for strings match?

Comment: The `if`condition at the beginning of `deepExtend` checks if the source property value was constructed from Object. Everything else is treated the same -- strings, arrays, numbers, booleans, and more. The bug only triggers when you the source is a Object and the destination is not.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, it checks h vs r value etc.

```js
var item = {
  prop: {
    "color": {
      "value": {
        h: 356, // or r: 356
        s: 76, // or: s: 76
        l: 41 // or b: 41
      }
    }
  }
}

colorresult = {};
var color = item.prop.color;
if ((color.value.h || color.value.b) && (color.value.s || color.value.g)&& (color.value.l || color.value.b)) {
  colorresult.rgb = {
    r: color.value.h || color.value.r,
    g: color.value.s || color.value.g,
    b: color.value.l || color.value.b
  }
}

console.log(colorresult)
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. The colors still don't change. Let me create a fiddle :).

Comment: I doubt if it is issue, `this` is issue in `this.color.rgb` as well

Answer (score -1):

you need to see the below link

http://www.softarc.com/Resources/Tips/ExternalApps/Resources/TemplateDocs/lessons/Using_JSON_strings_to_store_data.html